# jquery ajax return data not working

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have a form with two text boxes and two buttons (one submit button, one button). when I call click the button, it has to make an ajax call with data "CheckRegistration". Finally, it will call ViewRegisteredStudents() function. I am expecting the "resultVal" stirng to be returned to ajax call but it is returning the "resultVal" string and form (two textboxes, two buttons).

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

             $(':button').click(function(){
                  $.ajax({
                      Url:"SkiiTripDB.php",
                      type:"POST",
                      data:{call:'CheckRegistration'},
                      dataType:"html",
                      success:function(data){
                             $('div#registeredStudents').html(data);
                      }
                  });
              });

          });
```

---

```
      if(isset($_POST['call']))
        {
                $call=$_POST['call'];

                  $connection=IsDatabaseConnected($strServer,$strUsername,$strPassword,$strDatabaseName);
                 switch($call)
                 {
                      case 'CheckRegistration':ViewRegisteredStudents();
                                                break;
                 }
                 closeDatabaseConnection($connection);   
         }

function ViewRegisteredStudents()
        {
           $resultVal="";
           $resultVal.="<table  border='2'>";
           $resultVal.="<tr>";
           $resultVal.="    <th>Student Name</th>";
           $resultVal.="     <th>Student Class</th>";
           $resultVal.=" </tr>";

           // Query database
           $strSqlQuery="SELECT sSName, sClass FROM tripregistration";

           $result=mysql_query($strSqlQuery);

           while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
           {
               $resultVal.="<tr>";
                $resultVal.="<td>".$row['sSName']."</td>";
                $resultVal.="<td>".$row['sClass']."</td>";
               $resultVal.="</tr>";
           }
                $resultVal.="</table>";

              echo $resultVal;

            }
```

Comment: why did you pasted the codes from `javascript` and `php` in same blockquote? It's messing with my brain ...

Comment: Hi, I am sorry. now, I seperated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AJAX call see the parameter
***Url:"SkiiTripDB.php"*** in  *Url* U is capital convert it to lowercase.

Comment: Hi Anup, It worked for me ! can you explain the difference between Url  and url. thanks.

Comment: @dotnetrocks The case is different. JavaScript is case-sensitive.